# Animations Disappear When Loading Up Blender

Tags: animation

So, I was working on some animations the day before, and I saved my file and clicked the F in the action editor next to the ones I wanted saved (There were some other animations that I didn't know how to delete), and went to bed. When I woke up the next day, I started up the file, and all of my animations were gone. Does anyone know why this is? Is there some sort of way to save your animation, or is that what the F does, even though I pressed it?

By the way, I got then back by re-loading my old save file, I just want to know why that happened. Let me know if you need any extra details. Thanks!

Comment: Did you save *after* pressing F next to the animation tracks (as I understand you mean either NLA strips or actions in Action Editor) ?

Comment: Not an answer to the question: you can go back to the point where you were before turning the computer off by "recovering autosave" or "Recover Last Session". If you closed blender using quit, the last session would be saved as "quit.blend' file on your tmp folder.

Comment: Yes, I press F, looked at the animation a bit, then saved my file.

Comment: Try reloading your saved file, instead of using the autoload last session, which should be the same, but it isn't.

Comment: I already solved it at the time I posted it, but I just wanted to know if it was a bug or not. Judging from the answers, it was most likely a bug. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The **F** toggle is something many of us animators have complaints about. Yes it has to be selected to keep *Actions* if you start a new *Action*. The **F** toggle stands for **Fake User**. When you start a new *Action* via the **Action Editor** the *Action* that you had is removed from the *Armature*. As objects can only use 1 *Action* at a time.

The correct way to use multiple actions is to use the **NLA Editor**. There are new buttons in the **Action Editor's Header**: **Push Down** and **Stash**. You can use those to save your *Actions* in the **NLA Editor** so that they don't get deleted.